Slightly wrong name of company inviting me
I am invited by a company to give a conference in the UK in December. I already applied online for a standard visitor visa and paid fees of visa and appointment. I noticed that in the application I wrote that the name of the company is "Company X Holdings LTD" which is actually the American subsidiary company of the firm while the UK one is named "Company X LLC UK". What can I do ?

Who actually invited you? What is the name on their letter of invitation?

The company invited me, its written "Company X LLC UK" on the letter of invitation. Think of Company X as Coca-Cola for example that has many offices in the world. In the online application I wrote Company X Holdings LTD which same firm but the name is for the american-based "version"

It's quite common to have a situation where a firm operates in different countries with a locally-incorporated subsidiary company even if most things are controlled from the global HQ. I can't speak specifically for UK visa processing, but it's probably something they'll be familiar with and I wouldn't worry too much, as long as it's clear they're the same company (how big and well-known the company is might be relevant).
